# PhantomJS doesn't get the next page clicking in link controlled by JavaScript

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using `PhantomJS` with `Selenium WebDriver` to iterate over a set of pages where there is a button that encapsules a link where you can click to go to the next page as showed bellow:

```
<a href="javascript:GetNextPage(1, 12949)" class="next lnkPagination" rel="nofollow">&nbsp;</a>
```

The first parameter of `javascript:GetNextPage` changes dynamically according to the current page my application is on. I tried to simulate this behaviour with Firefox Selenium's WebDriver and it worked, however when I simulated with PhantomJS Webdriver I couldn't iterate because my application stuck in the first page forever.

Below is the exactly point of my application code where I'm doing this iteration. I was expecting `current_page_index` changed in each iteration, but it didn't and stopped in `1` and my while loop lasts forever:

```
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(response.url)

    while True:
        next_page_link = driver\
                         .find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='next lnkPagination']")\
                         .get_attribute("href")

        node = re.search("GetNextPage\((\d+),\%20(\d+)\)", next_page_link)
        current_page_index = int(node.group(1))
        last_page_index = int(node.group(2))
        .
        .
        . 
        if current_page_index == last_page_index:
            break

        # Just click to next page if the next page element has rendered on the page
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            if driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"):
                break

        driver.get(next_page_link)


    driver.quit()
```

Is there any reason why it worked in Firefox WebDriver, but didn't in PhantomJS WebDriver?

I'd appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspicious:

```
    if driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"):
```

My guess is that it always evaluates to true in phantomjs, while it evaluates to false in Firefox.

I would change it to something more stable, such as:

```
    String readyState = driver.execute_script("return document.readyState");
    if (readyState != "complete"):
```